# HTML gmail not showing background colors?

Tags: css, gmail, html-email

I have this embedded CSS in a PHP program, to display background colors for the table.

```
<style>
table {
    width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color:#ffffff;
}
table#t01 th    {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

I have this:

```
<TABLE id="t01">
```

I have taken the raw output of this PHP program, saved it as a .html file, uploaded it to a server and it behaves as I expected. But when as HTML gmail, it doesn't display the background colors at all.

If I added in the HTML on  to do bgcolor="black" that works. So I know it must be possible to do background colors in html gmail, but apparently not have I'm doing it here.

The PHP program generates the tables and I really want to have the CSS take care of the odd/even colors for the rows.

What is the elegant programming solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gmail strips the head and body tags completely and only recognizes certain elemental stylings in the style tag.

You will need to inline the styles. To take care of this, I would programatically build your email and then run it through an inliner.  [This is a good example of one from Mailchimp](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/).

This should solve your issue, but you may run into issue with any media queries or similar items you wish to retain in the head tag. I would make sure to test your email across all devices every time you run it through the inliner to ensure it works correctly cross-client.

Comment: Thanks!!! I found a PHP inliner:
https://gist.github.com/barock19/1591053#file-premailer-php

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you have PHP in a file you have to name it `.PHP`

Secondly use in-line elements because like Gortonington said Gmail and some other Email clients strip the  tag out

By this I mean

```
<TABLE id="t01" style="width:100px; height:100px; font-size:12px;>
```

And like you wanted:

```
<table style="background-color:black;border-collapse: collapse; width:100%;">
```

And so on.

Hope this helps :)
-Shaun

P.S if you want to write all you CSS out like a normal webpage then put the classes on your elements use [this tool](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)

Comment: An external tool isn't useful, since it's a PHP program that is generating the HTML e-mail for gmail. But this solved the problem:
https://gist.github.com/barock19/1591053#file-premailer-php